# Magento2 image resize

Tags: magento2

How to resize product image to a perfect rectangle without white spaces at right and left.

At present we are using 1200*1200 size image, and resizing to 450*300

in result we are getting 450*300 image but white space exits

please help us to fix this issue in magento2

We are using this code presently

```
<?php

$_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->resize(450, 300);

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set ObjectManager in constructor `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $objectManager;`

```
$imageHelper  = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(450, 300)->getUrl();
```

Comment: If it works, You can correct the answer as well as up-vote so it will help others.
Thanks.